# Fill in data from another table using ranges in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, fill

I'm filling empty arrivals time in a bus timetable, I have start,end and some midpoints times, I do by calculating average speed between start and end route, but results are inexact, so must use intervals speed to compute arrivals times.
General Timetable shown in First Code Snippet, please run to see table, and Computed arrival times for Intervals in Second Code Snippet .
What I'm trying to do is to fill in av_speed ingeneral timetable with Intervals average speed, i.e. put 251.17 into timetable stops_sequences 1 to 5, 230.68 into sequences 6 to 10 and so on.

```
+============+===============+==============+==========+===========+===========+==========+
| stoptimeid | stop_sequence | arrival_time | distance | dist_trav | time_trav | av_speed |
+============+===============+==============+==========+===========+===========+==========+
| 54689      | 1             | 6:05:00      | 0,00     |           |           | 220,98   |
| 54690      | 2             |              | 0,35     |           |           | 220,98   |
| 54691      | 3             |              | 0,49     |           |           | 220,98   |
| 54692      | 4             |              | 0,91     |           |           | 220,98   |
| 54693      | 5             | 6:10:00      | 1,19     |           |           | 220,98   |
| 54694      | 6             |              | 1,50     |           |           | 220,98   |
| 54695      | 7             |              | 1,67     |           |           | 220,98   |
| 54696      | 8             |              | 1,96     |           |           | 220,98   |
| 54697      | 9             |              | 2,16     |           |           | 220,98   |
| 54698      | 10            | 6:15:00      | 2,49     |           |           | 220,98   |
| 54699      | 11            |              | 2,64     |           |           | 220,98   |
| 54700      | 12            |              | 3,11     |           |           | 220,98   |
| 54701      | 13            |              | 3,79     |           |           | 220,98   |
| 54702      | 14            |              | 4,14     |           |           | 220,98   |
| 54703      | 15            |              | 4,39     |           |           | 220,98   |
| 54704      | 16            |              | 4,96     |           |           | 220,98   |
| 54705      | 17            |              | 5,10     |           |           | 220,98   |
| 54706      | 18            | 6:25:00      | 5,21     |           |           | 220,98   |
+============+===============+==============+==========+===========+===========+==========+
```

```
+============+===============+==============+==========+===========+===========+==========+
| stoptimeid | stop_sequence | arrival_time | distance | dist_trav | time_trav | av_speed |
+============+===============+==============+==========+===========+===========+==========+
| 54689      | 1             | 6:05:00      | 0,00     |           |           |          |
| 54693      | 5             | 6:10:00      | 1,19     | 1,194423  | 300       | 251,17   |
| 54698      | 10            | 6:15:00      | 2,49     | 1,300520  | 300       | 230,68   |
| 54706      | 18            | 6:25:00      | 5,21     | 2,715214  | 600       | 220,98   |
+============+===============+==============+==========+===========+===========+==========+
```

Have checked the use of a CASE function that fills in descending order, fills 18 to 1, then fills 10 to 5 and finally 5 to 1, so final result it's ok.

This is what I tried but only fill with only one av_speed, the last one.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW arrivaltime_check AS
SELECT
CASE
WHEN arrivaltime.stop_sequence<=foo.stop_sequence  THEN foo.av_speed
ELSE foo.av_speed END,foo.trip_id2,foo.stop_sequence
FROM
    public.arrivaltime,
(SELECT 
    b.rid,
    b.trip_id2,
    b.stoptimeid,
    b.stop_sequence,
    b.arrival_time,
    extract(epoch from (b.arrival_time)) as time_epoch,
    b.distance,
    b.distance -lag(b.distance,1) over (partition by b.trip_id2 ) as      dist_trav,
    b.time_epoch -lag(b.time_epoch,1) over (partition by b.trip_id2 ) as time_trav,
    (b.time_epoch -lag(b.time_epoch,1) over (partition by b.trip_id2 ))/(b.distance -lag(b.distance,1) over (partition by b.trip_id2 )) as av_speed
from    public.timecalc1 b

    order by b.trip_id2,b.stop_sequence desc) foo;
```

foo subquery only computes values when arrivaltimes is not null,

How can I fill in timetable with intervals av_speed?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Edit, added tables as html snipept, it's ok?

Comment: Thanks, sorry for any inconvenience.